# Creating custom crawled properties in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: fast-search, crawled-property

In Sharepoint 2013, can I create a custom crawled property that can, for example, retrieve the content of the attribute Class of all the tags div?

Answer (score 1):

By utilizing a content enrichment webservice you could pass in the HTML and use eg. HTML Agility Pack to parse it. The write out the values you want to a new managed property.

So no crawled properties involved.

I'm also a bit curious as to the use case here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. The property is not the Problem, but getting the divs's classes. For that you need a custom connector that parses the webpage and fills the property - in other words a lot of work.